# Gradient vs exterior derivative

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, reference-request, riemannian-geometry

I have a very basic question. Suppose one has a function $u \in L^2(M) \cap C^\infty(M)$, where $M$ is a complete Riemannian manifold. Suppose we wish to prove that $u \in H^1(M)$, which includes the additional step of proving that $\nabla u \in L^2(M)$. My question is, is this the same as proving $du \in L^2(M)$, where $d$ represents the exterior derivative? Here, the norm on $\nabla u$ comes from the Riemannian metric by considering $\nabla u(x)$ as a tangent vector at $x$, and the norm on $df$ is given from the Hodge $\ast$-operator, where the $L^2$-norm on any $p$-form $\alpha$ is given by $\| \alpha \|^2 = \int_M (\alpha \wedge \ast\alpha) \; dV$.

Comment: As far as I know, the metric introduces an isometry $T_pM \simeq T_p^*M$. So really, the $L^2$ norms of $|du|_g$ and $|\nabla u|_g$ should really be the same. The definition of the norm on forms from the Hodge operator is actually equivalent to the isometric prescription above by virtue of the relation
$$
\alpha \wedge \star \beta = (\alpha, \beta)_g \text{vol}
$$